# using netbeans, can i decipher d design of a form from the code (javaframe forms)?

Tags: java, forms, netbeans

i got java code for jframe form.
 using this code i wud like the netbeans to construct a form.

> i tried replacing d new form file in d saved project directory using d existing java form file, but however d code was replaced , but not the form.

so plz help

Comment: Did you try and search the internet for answers?

Comment: my friend gave the code of a javaframe form , but not design of d form, so can i create d form from the existing code??

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get the designer view of Netbeans if your form (JFrame) was not designed with Netbeans. Still you can use Netbeans, but only as a sophisticated text editor. It should be quite easy though to design a replica with the NB-designer, if you have the specifications, if you take a look at the source code you have been given or have an image of your form.

Comment: it was designed with netbeans , but an older version. 
so netbeans cannot decipher the design from code, am i r8?

Comment: You should have one .form file for every form then, that start like this:            <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Form version="1.3" maxVersion="1.7" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JFrameFormInfo">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="defaultCloseOperation" type="int" value="3"/>
  </Properties>
  <SyntheticProperties>

Comment: i've got only the code of the frame, i dont have the corresponding .form file.
so is there a possibility that an ide can decipher the form from the generated code?

Comment: i'm afraid it is not possible.